# NaN output, i can't find out why

Tags: java

I am creating code to help myself with some homework, but there is a problem with class 'C'. It keeps giving me NaN output, can You look at it and tell me what am I doing wrong?

I double check it and found out problem lies it this line:

```
C[i][j] = C[i][j] * (Math.sqrt(((Math.pow(U[i][j],2)/Math.pow(I[i][j],2)))-Math.pow(R[i],2)));
```

Main -

```
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Wzory wzor = new Wzory();
            wzor.scan();
            wzor.xU();
            wzor.xI();
            wzor.C();

        }

    }
```

```
package FizA;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Wzory {
    //przypisane
    double[] f = new double[2],xf = new double[2],R = new double[2],xR = new double[2];
    double[][] U = new double[2][4],I = new double[2][4];
    double pi=3.1415;
    //obliczone
    double[][] xU = new double[2][4], xI = new double[2][4], C = new double[2][4], xC = new double[2][4];


    public void scan()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Podaj 'f':");
            f[i] = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Podaj 'xf':");
            xf[i] = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Podaj 'R':");
            R[i] = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Podaj 'xR':");
            xR[i] = scan.nextDouble();
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("Podaj 'U':");
                U[i][j] = scan.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Podaj 'I':");
                I[i][j] = scan.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }

    public void xU()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            {
                xU[i][j] = 0.005 * U[i][j];
                xU[i][j] = xU[i][j] + 0.003;    
                System.out.println("xU-"+i+","+j+"="+xU[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }

    public void xI()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            {
                xI[i][j] = 0.015 * I[i][j];
                xI[i][j] = xI[i][j] + 0.000003;
                System.out.println("xI"+i+","+j+"="+xI[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void C()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            {
                C[i][j] = 2*pi*f[i];
                C[i][j] = C[i][j] * (Math.sqrt(((Math.pow(U[i][j],2)/Math.pow(I[i][j],2)))-Math.pow(R[i],2)));
                C[i][j] = Math.pow(C[i][j],-1);
                System.out.println("C"+i+","+j+"="+C[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: your function name is `C` and your Array name is also `C`. and what is `pi` and `f` and other arrays. post more code

Comment: I put almost all code, and specified where the problem is in the description

Comment: What's your sample input and expected output? `NaN` usually occurs when you try to compute something like `0.0 / 0.0`. Make sure you don't do that.

Comment: Podaj 'f':
480
Podaj 'xf':
1
Podaj 'R':
250
Podaj 'xR':
12
Podaj 'U':
1
Podaj 'I':
0,43
Podaj 'U':
1,502
Podaj 'I':
0,65
Podaj 'U':
2
Podaj 'I':
0,87
Podaj 'U':
2,512
Podaj 'I':
1,1
Podaj 'f':
380
Podaj 'xf':
1
Podaj 'R':
250
Podaj 'xR':
12
Podaj 'U':
1
Podaj 'I':
0,33
Podaj 'U':
1,52
Podaj 'I':
0,52
Podaj 'U':
2,007
Podaj 'I':
0,69
Podaj 'U':
2,515
Podaj 'I':
0,87
C0,0=NaN
C0,1=NaN
C0,2=NaN
C0,3=NaN
C1,0=NaN
C1,1=NaN
C1,2=NaN
C1,3=NaN

Comment: Have you inspected the computed values based on this input during a debugging session? Do you know [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Plus, I see no `main` method there. How do you call those methods?

Comment: No, I didn't. I will look into it now. But there is no warning/errors.

Comment: Wzory wzor = new Wzory();
  wzor.scan();
  wzor.xU();
  wzor.xI();
  wzor.C();

Comment: You should've included both your input and the call of `Wzory` methods in your question.

Comment: I would like to but site says - "Too much code"

Comment: I checked this values, and they are fine

Comment: Then you should've spent some time thinking how to extract the minimal example. Do you know about [mcve]? It's crucial to think it through and contruct it first before posting here.

Comment: My post is now uptated and You are able to see my whole code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking a square root of this, Math.pow(U[i][j],2)/Math.pow(I[i][j],2)))-Math.pow(R[i],2)

Your NaN comes from:

1) the Math.sqrt method

2) and the minus Math.pow(R[i],2), since negative numbers don't have a square root, a square is either a 0 or a positive number.

Example:

When U[i][j] to the power of 2 / I[i][j] to the power of 2, minus R[i] to the power of 2, gives a negative number, your Math.sqrt of this negative number will give an NaN, even though you multiply it with C[i][j] and store it back in C[i][j] and print it.

That's how you get an NaN.

Comment: Ah, couple of seconds before I posted my answer :) That's the correct explanation of the problem.